# Data conversion in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with dataset which contain numerical values stored as type object. Below you can see how is look like data in pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

[image]

So I want to convert this columns from object type into int64 . In order to do this  I try with this line of code

```
X['duration']=X['duration'].astype('float64')
```

But this line not don't work well and give this error message:

```
could not convert string to float: '18`'
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this and convert into numerical values ?

Comment: Can you provide the full column as text? The problematic values like aren't in the image you pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pd.to_numeric -

```
X['duration'] = X['duration'].str.extract('(\d+)')
X['duration'] = pd.to_numeric(X['duration'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(['18\`'], errors="coerce")` gives `array([nan])` as output

Comment: Yup. @jakub. In that case, you need to use regex on the string column 1st to grab the digits.  and then you can use it.

Comment: I think that would be a better answer than coercing some values to nan.